# Tokenizing a string using negations

Tags: java, regex, token

So i have the following problem: 
I have to `tokenize` a string using `String.split()` and the tokens must be in the form `07dd ddd ddd`, where d is a digit. I thought of using the following regex : `^(07\\d{2}\\s\\d{3}\\d{3})` and pass it as an argument to String.split(). But for some reason, although i do have substrings under that form, it outputs the whole initial string and doesn't tokenize it.

I initially thought that it was using an empty string as a splitter, as an empty string indeed matches that regex, but even after I added `& (.)+` to the regex in order to assure that the splitter hasn't got length 0, it still outputs the whole initial string.

I know that i could have used `Pattern's` and `Matchers` to solve it much faster, but i have to use String.split(). Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Show us sample input and output..

Comment: Is `0712 345 679` one token or is that an input that should be split into 3 tokens on spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Few Pointers

- Your pattern `^(07\d{2}\s\d{3}\d{3})` is missing a space between the two last groups of digits
- The reason you get the whole string back is that this pattern was never found in the first place: there is no split
- If you split on this pattern (once fixed), the resulting array will be strings that are **in-between** this pattern (these tokens are actually removed)
- If you want to use this pattern (once fixed), you need a Match All not a Split. This will look like `arrayOfMatches = yourString.match(/pattern/g);`
- If you want to split, you need to use a delimiter that is present between the token (this delimiter could in fact just be a zero-width position asserted by the `07` about to follow)

**Further Reading**

[Match All and Split are Two Sides of the Same Coin](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch)

Comment: @AaronDigulla Or at the start of a line, if in multi-line mode. I know. It's not quite ready for prime-time, as I mentioned with the missing space. :)